# tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row: for view-based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

According to [Apple's documentation on `[NSTableViewDelegate tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:]`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:), "this method is only valid for NSCell-based table views". What's its equivalent for view-based table views? I would like to replace the default inline-editing with a custom editing experience.

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: View-based table views are expected to use `NSImageView`, `NSTextField`, `NSImageView` and etc. for their cells, so it does not make sense to have `[NSTableViewDelegate tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:]` which is something associated more with text editing (by default cell-based views use `NSTextFieldCell` for cells and it contains only text). If you want to control the editing of a text cell, you can use `NSTextField` and set `[NSTextField setEditable:NO]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually no need in this delegate method with view-based table views.

In that case you need to create, for example, some NSView-subclass. There may be nib-file too.

Let's say, you have a class named CustomCellView having some outlets. `CustomCellView.h` file

```
#define kCustomCellViewReusableIdentifier @"kCustomCellViewReusableIdentifier" // NSTableView reuses cell views

@interface CustomCellView : NSView

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;

- (void)setCellEditable:(BOOL)editable;

@end
```

Here's your `CustomCellView.m` file

```
@implementation CustomCellView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  // paste your ui initializing code here
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
  // this method will call each time cell reuses
}

- (void)setCellEditable:(BOOL)editable
{
  [self.textField setEditable:editable];
  // some other code
}

@end
```

Don't forget to create nib-file and connect your outlets. Your NSTableView owner class must have some initializing code for reusing. `MyTableViewController.m`

```
- (void)initUI
{
  NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass([CustomCellView class]);
  [self.tableView registerNib:[[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:nibName bundle:nil]
                 forIdentifier:kCustomCellViewReusableIdentifier];
}

#pragma mark - table view data source methods

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
   CustomCellView *view=[tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:kCustomCellViewReusableIdentifier owner:nil];
   [view setCellEditable:someCondition]; // 
   return view;
}

#pragma mark - operations

- (void)setViewAtColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row editable:(BOOL)editable
{
  CustomCellView *view=[self.tableView viewAtColumn:tableColumn row:row makeIfNecessary:NO]; //no need to create it if it's not exists - we'll set the data in NSTableViewDataSource method
  if (view) // if it's exists
    [view setCellEditable:editable];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Commenting on Astoria's approach:

The inconvient "problem" with having to change the editability of the text field whenever the editability of the model changes, is that you have to "actively" track the editibility of the model and update the text field's editability.

By contrast, the cell-based table view's delegate approach defers caring about editability until the very moment the user attempts to make an edit, at which point the delegate simply returns whether the model can be edited or not. There's a lot less setup, and a less potential for making a mistake. (eg, depending on how you're monitoring/responding to editability in the model, you may miss a change and now the user can incorrectly edit or not edit the field.)

So a different approach is to recreate the delegation of determining editability at the moment the user attempts to edit. To do this, you'd subclass `NSTextField`, override the "right spot", ask the delegate, and allow or disallow editablity.

The "right spot" would seem to be overriding `acceptsFirstResponder`, and returning NO.

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    BOOL accepts = [super acceptsFirstResponder];

    if (accepts) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldBecomeEditable:)]) {
            accepts = [self.delegate textFieldShouldBecomeEditable:self];
        }
    }

    return accepts;
}
```

With the above, as long as the field's `editable` is YES, the delegate is called to have final determination.

Depending on your application, this may be a more desirable approach because monitoring changes to the model's editability is not straight forward. However, generally, the standard approach of simply setting the field's `editable` property is best.

Answer (score 0):

Following [seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2150405/seth)'s answer I came up with this; need the objects (item) context, along with column and tableView info. HTH

```
//  We cannot alter a playitem once plays is non-zero; set to zero to alter
@objc func textFieldShouldBecomeEditable(_ textField: PlayTableTextField) -> Bool {
    let tableView = textField.superview?.superview?.superview as! PlayTableView
    let item = (textField.superview as! PlayTableCellView).objectValue
    let tableColumn = textField.tableColumn!

    if tableView == playlistTableView, let playlist : PlayList = item as? PlayList {
        guard playlist.name != UserSettings.HistoryName.value else { return false }
        return tableColumn.identifier == .name
    }
    else
    if tableView == playitemTableView, let playitem : PlayItem = item as? PlayItem {
        let virgin = playitem.plays == 0

        guard playitem.name != UserSettings.HistoryName.value else { return false }

        switch tableColumn.identifier {
        case .link:
            return !virgin && !appDelegate.isSandboxed

        case .plays:
            return true

        default:
            return virgin || ![.link,.plays].contains(tableColumn.identifier)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}
```